# Jquery - How to convert Array of Object to Json string

Tags: jquery, json

There is `SymbologyObject` and `ValuesArray`:

```
var SymbologyObject = {};
var ValuesArray = [];
```

Put something into them like below:

```
var ValueOfField = "tree";
ValuesArray[ValueOfField] = [];

var localStyle = {};
localStyle.fill = "#ffff";
localStyle.stroke = "#cccc";
localStyle.width = 3;
localStyle.value = ValueOfField;

ValuesArray[ValueOfField] = localStyle;

SymbologyObject.type = "Unique";
SymbologyObject.label = "test";

SymbologyObject.attr = "attribute";

SymbologyObject.values = ValuesArray;
```

When I use `console.log(SymbologyObject);` output is:

```
attr:"attribute"
label:"test"
type:"Unique"
values:
tree:{fill: "#ffff", stroke: "#cccc", width: "3", value: "tree"}
```

I convert it to json:

```
JSON.stringify(SymbologyObject);
```

output of above code:

```
{"type":"Unique","label":"test","attr":"attribute","values":[]}
```

but i want below output:

```
{"type":"Unique","label":"test","attr":"attribute","values":[tree:{"fill": "#ffff", "stroke": "#cccc", "width": "3", "value": "tree"}]}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your variable initialize is wrong.
you have to initialize like below.

```
var SymbologyObject = {};
var ValuesArray = {}; //<< CHANGE
```

Second, see the change below.

```
var ValueOfField = "tree";
ValuesArray[ValueOfField] = {}; //<<CHANGE

var localStyle = {};
localStyle.fill = "#ffff";
localStyle.stroke = "#cccc";
localStyle.width = 3;
localStyle.value = ValueOfField;

ValuesArray[ValueOfField] = localStyle;

SymbologyObject.type = "Unique";
SymbologyObject.label = "test";

SymbologyObject.attr = "attribute";

SymbologyObject.values = ValuesArray;
```

so, the output will be like below.

```
{"type":"Unique","label":"test","attr":"attribute","values":{"tree1":{"fill":"#ffff","stroke":"#cccc","width":3,"value":"tree1"},"tree":{"fill":"#ffff","stroke":"#cccc","width":3,"value":"tree"}}}
```

Comment: I want output like this: `{"type":"Unique","label":"test","attr":"attribute","values":[tree:{"fill": "#ffff", "stroke": "#cccc", "width": "3", "value": "tree"}]}`. array,not object.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you check your JSON as it is not a valid JSOn.
`

```
{
    "type": "Unique",
    "label": "test",
    "attr": "attribute",
    "values": [tree: {
        "fill": "#ffff",
        "stroke": "#cccc",
        "width": "3",
        "value": "tree"
    }]
}
```

`